# android annotations, gradle and robolectric: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/androidannotations/api/view/HasViews

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric, android-annotations

I've successfully managed to get Robolectric working in an gradle project. Now I have a problem getting it to work with Android Annotations. Therefore I have already joined the test package and the main package (Generated classes of Android Annotations have only package visibility). I've read the section about unit testing at https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Unit-test-your-application.

Any test not concerning activities works well, for example:

```
@Test
public void testTrueIsTrue() throws Exception {
    Assertions.assertThat(true);
}
```

Now the problem is, when trying to execute a test concerning activities and their lifecycles the test fails with a NoClassDefFoundError. Do you have an idea how to get activities tested? A test concerning this is e.g.:

```
@Test
public void testActivity() {
    MainActivity_ mainActivity = new MainActivity_();
    mainActivity.onCreate(null);
    Assert.assertNotNull(mainActivity);
}
```

or

```
@Test
public void testRobolectricActivity() {
    ActionBarActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity_.class).create().get();
    Assert.assertNotNull(activity);
}
```

The resulting Error and its stacktrace for the last test is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/project/app/ui/MainActivity_
at path.to.project.test.MainActivityRobolectricTest.testRobolectricActivity(MainActivityRobolectricTest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

For the first test

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/androidannotations/api/view/HasViews
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.findClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:165)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:98)
at path.to.projet.test.MainActivityRobolectricTest.testActivity(MainActivityRobolectricTest.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.androidannotations.api.view.HasViews
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.findClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:131)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:98)... 43 more
```

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the stacktrace you can also see how I structured my packages now. Is this still a problem maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used roboelectric but it sounds like either AA isn't generating the classes.

Look in the apt_generated folder for MainAcitvity_ check that the file is there and it has the  hasviews method.

Secondly does this make a difference casting to the non generated class

```
@Test
public void testActivity() {
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity_();
    mainActivity.onCreate(null);
    Assert.assertNotNull(mainActivity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The problem is that the generated classes are still not found due to an error.
And I see you are also using the SNAPSHOT version, which I also had.

I'm not sure but in my case Android Annotations didn't tell me that there was an error in my annotated code but I checked the recently coded methods and realized that one of my methods annotated with @Background had private access. This was the problem. After making it package local everything worked again.

Another problem could be that you didn't correctly specify the build directory in your tests vm option. Therefore you have to do the following:

Reset your vm options under edit configurations to -ea (default).
After that you will get a STUB! exception when executing your test, which complains about the junit version. Copy everything on top of the exception console (it is slightly grey and you'll have to open it) into an editor, delete everything before -classpath and everything at the end which is not belonging to the classpath (means not separated by : and append behind the last path your build directory:

Looks like this in my case:

```
-classpath /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12-SNAPSHOT/d0f5ec9e335da2ea2827c781a46a02d8b6bbd556/junit-4.12-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/user/android-studio/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/user/android-studio/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/home/user/android-sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar:/home/user/android-sdk/platforms/android-19/data/res:/home/user/android-sdk/tools/support/annotations.jar:   [... deleted some dependencies here ...]   /home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric/2.4-SNAPSHOT/78161192eaadd6c7c56f6cf48040fa46897163d0/robolectric-2.4-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/5.0.1/7c8caddfbd0b2d7b844f8fcc75175b9cb9cf4724/asm-util-5.0.1.jar:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3-SNAPSHOT/90850100a41d5695e2780773e2fc33198dea70d/gson-2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/user/development/App/app/build/generated
```

After that the classes should be found.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem without see your project setup. I can you just show that robolectric and android annotations works together. Here in my example app template with activity testing https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template